# foreach not applicable to type org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, design

Конструкцию цикла for последнее время принято записывать упощённо без явного использования индекса, вроде бы понятно как это делать и всегда работало, но тут столкнулся с такой ситуацией:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

try {
            JSONObject JOAnswer = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray arr = JOAnswer.getJSONArray(fieldsJSON.rows.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                Double latitude = obj.getDouble(fieldsJSON.latitude.toString());
                Double longitude = obj.getDouble(fieldsJSON.longitude.toString());
[.. ]
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Выше код, который можно было бы записать без индекса. Типа:

`for(JSONObject obj : arr)`

Однако что-то идёт не так. (foreach not applicable to type org.json.JSONArray). 
 Может я что-то не понимаю и for всё-таки можно записать без явного перебора индекса?

Comment: Очевидно, JsonArray не итерабельный. Зайдите в исходный код и посмотрите как он устроен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach работает только для классов, реализующих интерфейс java.lang.Iterable. JSONArray не реализует этот интерфейс, поэтому с ним нельзя работать через foreach. Вы можете реализовать паттерн Wrapper, завернуть в него JSONArray, реализовав во Wrapper и Iterable. Но замена for на foreach того не стоит.